# How can I set the initially focused element without activating the window (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, focus

My program creates a window with `ShowActivated=false`, so that it doesn't steal keyboard focus when it's opened (the window is created in response to events coming over the network).  I want to be able to specify that a particular TextBox field receives focus when the user switches to the window.  However, the seemingly obvious methods (using `FocusManager.FocusedElement` in the window's markup, or calling `this.textbox.Focus()` when the window is shown) have the side effect of activating the window.

I ended up adding an event handler for the window's `Activated` event, which (a) makes the desired `Focus()` call, and (b) removes itself from the `Activated` event, so that it only happens once.  This seems crufty.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Why crufty? It seems simple enough. And it works around a standard behavior, where there's no other easy way (I think). I'd do the same.